# How to read file from other application (in its private cache dir) with my application

Tags: android, file

I have an application (commercial one) that create a data file (csv format) in its cache directory. I need to read this data file within my application to analyse the data.

But when i try to read with inputStream method the file with its absolute path access i catch an exeption *permission denied*.

So I suppose i must change or demand permission but i dont exactly understand. I am beginner in android development I read some articles on *content provider, external storage* but nothing to resolve my problem . Could you help me please?...

My code:

```
List<String> RowDataFile = new ArrayList<String>();

    FileInputStream input = null;
    String filePath = "storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.lifescan.reveal/cache";
    //String filePath = "storage/emulated/0/Android/data/vincent.gridlayout/files";
    File f = new File(filePath,"/data.csv");

    try {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(f);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

        for (String line = br.readLine(); line != null; line = br.readLine()) {
            RowDataFile.add(line);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
```

The exception generated in the logcat :

08-12 12:37:21.254 30563-30563/vincent.gridlayout W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.lifescan.reveal/cache/data.csv: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

Android Device system : 4.4.2

and the manifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="vincent.heatMap">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".HeatMapEdit"></activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Thanks for your help...

Answer (score 3):

Based on your logcat output, this does not look like a simple manifest permissions issue. It looks like you are trying to access a file from the [internal storage cache](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal) of another application, which is *private* to that application.

In order for another application to share files from internal storage it must specify a `FileProvider` in its manifest. Take a look at the documentation on [Sharing Files](https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/index.html) in order to set up a `FileProvider` in one app, and request a shared file from another app.

> **Note:** Previously it was possible to access a file from the internal storage of a another app if that file was created using the
>   context modes `MODE_WORLD_READABLE` or `MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE`. Though,
>   both of these constants have been deprecated since API level 17, and
>   as of API level 24 their use will result in a `SecurityException`
>   being thrown.

Comment: I found the error...I missplaced the <uses-permission/> tag in the manifest !! it must be BEFORE the <application/> tag...but i dont understand why! Thanks for your answers, Vincent.